# Is shunting-yard algorithm needed if there is no parenthesis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

I am trying to find a permutation (with replacement) of operators(such as addition and multiplication) that makes numbers 1 2 3 , ..., 9 result in to some numbers.

My guess is to find all possible permutation with Cartesian products (8 times) of {operator set}, and append them after the numbers (e.g. 1 2 3 , ..., 9 + * + + * * ...) and evaluate them.

The question is, if I am not using parentheses, i.e. there is nothing like 1 + 2 * (3 + 4), am I safe to attach an array of 8 binary operators after the 9 numbers?

Or even in that case should I first construct the expression in in-fix, and convert it into Reverse Polish notation using Shunting-yard algorithm?

Also, will there be any further optimization or better algorithms that I could make use of?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you are asking the right question. If you had only 1,2,3,4,5 for example and wanted 1+2*3*4+5, you can't get it with reverse polish notation having 1,2,3,4,5 in that fixed order and then some arithmetic operators.

Comment: I am finding, say, combinations of * and + that results in 30. Then I will put 1 2 3 4 5 and all possible cases of 4 operators in stack, and evaluate them. It will find that the output of (1 2 3 4 5 + * * +) is 30, and will find other combinations.

Comment: No that doesn't work. That means you don't understand reverse polish notation. What your sequence will get is (5+4)*3*2+1.

Comment: You are right. I see that now. However, is there any way to put all numbers first and then all operators later and calculate them? For example if the array of numbers is 1 2 3, I want to test 1 + 2 + 3, 1 + 2 * 3, 1 * 2 + 3, 1 * 2 * 3. I first thought this would be done by putting 123++, 123*+, 123+*, 123**, but this does not work, esp. for larger array of numbers, because of the order of operators.

Comment: The easiest way I could think of was to make all possible in-fix expressions, and then convert them into Reverse Polish notation using Shunting-yard algorithm, and then evaluating the value. However, this is too complex, so I posted the question.

Comment: You still need to permute the numbers in some way because the total number of possible ways of evaluation is at least the number of valid bracket sequences times $4^{n-1}$.

Comment: I don't see why you need any conversion to reverse-polish notation in the first place. You can simply try all permutations of the digits.

Comment: I do not permute the numbers, just the operators. If I do, it will find more operator sequence that results in some number(say 100), because I am excluding cases where parentheses are used.

Comment: I don't see what is so good about expressions with only addition and multiplication and no brackets, but if you want that just do a depth-first search. At each step choose to either continue the current product or complete it and add to the current sum. Then choose an unused digit, which will either be multiplied to the current product or will start a new product.